# How can I know the outcome of the "return True" function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return

In the following code, if I run it on IDLE, it gives me no outcome.

But with the command return True, wasn't supposed to give me True on the outcome?

Or do I have to add something like print True?

```
data = [2,4,5,7,8,9,12,14,17,19,22,25,27,28,33,37]
target = 28

#Linear Search
def linear_search(data, target):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] == target:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Are you calling your function somewhere?

Comment: You are missing the line to call the function: result = linear_search(data, target)

Answer (score 3):

Only defining the function is not enough you also need to call it.
In your case so add following:

```
print(linear_search(data,target))
```